# Formatting Cells Number in Whole Excel Workbook Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a Macro that formats the whole woorkbook Excel cells as number.

I have this code:

`Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.00"`

But this only for a specific range.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `Range("A1:Z1000").NumberFormat = "0.00"` - Just change the values to what you want.

Comment: @braX But I want the whole woorkbook Excel, i. .e, all pages from a workbook.

Comment: Then loop it thru all the worksheets like the answer below does.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    sht.Cells.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Next sht
```

That should do the trick

Hmmm, I thought this would work:

```
Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Sheets.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

It *should* have worked given this did work:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Sheets.Select: Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

I must be missing something subtle in the syntax...

Comment: I think `NumberFormat` is not an available property of the `sheets` which is a collection level object. So in principle, it is applying to `Selection` object and therefore works.

Comment: Yep - certainly seems that way. I very much dislike using .Select though!

Answer (score 2):

This works to format all cells in all worksheets of you workbook.

```
Sub format_as_numbers()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Cells.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Next
End Sub
```

It has to be workbook in the .xlsx-Format because the older .xls Files dont have that much rows and columns, therefore it would fail to execute it ther i think.

Comment: Drop the "range" and replace it with "cells", i.e. ws.cells.NumberFormat and you are agnostic to xlsx and xls sizing differences.